# Shebang path is a bash script, not working as expected

Tags: bash, exec, shebang

The idea of the following is that shell script s1.sh is acting as the "interpreter" for script s2.

`s1.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hello world'
echo $@
```

`s2`:

```
#!/path/to/s1.sh
echo 'aaa'
```

When I run `./s2 x y z` my expectation is that it immediately execs `s1.sh`, passing the original script name along with the command line arguments, with output

```
$ ./s2 x y z
hello world
s2 x y z
```

In reality, what I get is

```
$ ./s2 x y z
aaa
```

Can someone explain why bash fails to exec `s1.sh` in spite of the shebang in `s2`?

Comment: `s1.sh` is subject to path lookup, and the current working directory isn't in your PATH, so when no executable is found, `bash` falls back to just executing `s2` with itself.

Comment: I thought that for a bit too, but it gives the same behavior with the full path specification.  I'll edit the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Works for me (Debian, linux 4.19) What's your OS (and version) Read your `execve` man page carefully. Mine says "Since Linux 2.6.28, the kernel permits the interpreter of a script to itself be a script."

Comment: This might be `bash` specific as well; it works as you want when I execute `./s2 x y z` from `zsh` (on macOS).

Comment: Why would you do this instead of just calling s1.sh from s2 (using exec if you feel  a burning urge to do so)?

Comment: Running macOS 11.6.  Haven't tried zsh yet, so could be a quirk of bash on Mac.